# Is there a way to list out all the active connections to a relying party application in a Service Namespace?

Tags: azure, servicebus

We would like list out all the active Senders and Listners for a given realm. Is there any API available to query the Service Bus for this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been getting that question several times in recents months. We're going to add better metrics to Service Bus in the next several months and the number of active listeners is one of the counters that's high up on the list. Senders is more difficult because that number is extremely volatile. We have a spec'd out feature to provide trends across a number of meters and senders is one where a trend is probably a reasonable way to show how the traffic looks.

I can't provide a better timeline for either, unfortunately.

Clemens